# function that given a list returns a list of list decreasing

Tags: python, list

I'd make a function in python, that given a list returns a list of list, in which every element is the list given decreased by one.

```
Input:  list_decreaser([0,3,4,5,6,7,8)

Output: [[0,3,4,5,6,7],[0,3,4,5,6],[0,3,4,5],[0,3,4],[0,3],[0]]
```

My attempt:

```
 def list_decreaser(list):  
      listresult = [] 
      for x in range(len(list)-1):
          list.remove(list[x])  
          listresult.append(list) 
      return listresult
```

Comment: `xs = [0,3,4,5,6,7,8]; output = [xs[:i] for i in range(len(xs)-1, 0, -1)]`

Comment: This is a duplicate of hundreds of questions, and is explained in the Python FAQ.

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't call a list `list`, as that hides the name of the type and constructor function.

Comment: As another side net, `list.remove(list[x])` is a very bad idea. If there are any duplicates in the list, like `[0, 1, 2, 0]`, how does it know whether you're trying to remove the second `0` or the first? What you want is `del list[x]`, or `list.pop(x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code appends the same list multiple times. It should append copy of the list.

And use `del list[..]` instead of `list.remove(list[..])` to delete an item at specific index.

```
def list_decreaser(xs):
    listresult = [] 
    for i in range(len(xs)-1, 0, -1): # <--- interate backward
        del xs[i]
        listresult.append(xs[:]) # <----
    return listresult

print(list_decreaser([0,3,4,5,6,7,8]))
```

Or using list comprehension:

```
>>> xs = [0,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> [xs[:i] for i in range(len(xs)-1, 0, -1)] 
[[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 3, 4, 5], [0, 3, 4], [0, 3], [0]]
```

BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name. It shadows builtin `list` function.

Comment: Or - [xs[:-i] for i in xrange(1,len(xs))]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're appending the same list over and over again. You keep mutating the list in-place, but you're never creating a new list. So you end up with a list of N references to the same empty list.

This is the same problem discussed in two FAQ questions. I think [How do I create a multidimensional list](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list) explains it best.

Anyway, what you need to do is append a new list each time through the loop. There are two ways to do that.

First, you can append a *copy* of the current list, instead of the list itself:

```
def list_decreaser(list):  
      listresult = [] 
      for x in range(len(list)-1):
          list.remove(list[x])
          listresult.append(list[:]) # this is the only change
      return listresult
```

This solves your problem, but it leaves a few new problems:

First, `list.remove(list[x])` is a very bad idea. If you give it, say, `[0, 1, 2, 0]`, what happens when you try to remove that second `0`? You're calling `list.remove(0)`, and there's no way the list can know you wanted the second `0` rather than the first! The right thing to do is call `del list[x]` or `list.pop(x)`.

But once you fix that, you're removing the elements from the wrong side. `x` is 0, then 1, then 2, and so on. You remove element 0, then element 1 (which is the original element 2), then element 2 (which is the original element 4), and eventually get an `IndexError`. Even if you fixed the "skipping an index" issue (which is also explained in the FAQ somewhere), you'd still be removing the first elements rather than the last ones. You can fix that by turning the range around. However, there's an even easier way: Just remove the last element each time, instead of trying to figure out which `x` is the right thing, which you can do by specifying `-1`, or just calling `pop` with no argument. And then you can use a much simpler loop, too:

```
def list_decreaser(list):  
      listresult = [] 
      while list:
          list.pop()
          listresult.append(list[:])
      return listresult
```

Of course this appends the last, empty list, which you apparently didn't want. You can fix that by doing `while len(list) >= 1`, or putting an `if list: listresult.append(list[:])`, or in various other ways.

---

Alternatively, you can make new truncated lists instead of truncating and copying the same list over and over:

```
def list_decreaser(list):  
      listresult = [] 
      while len(list):
          list = list[:-1]
          listresult.append(list)
      return listresult
```

Note that in this second version, rather than changing the value stored in `list`, we're creating a new list and storing that new list in `list`.

Comment: `range(len(list)-1)` should be reversed like `range(len(xs)-1, 0, -1)`.

Comment: @falsetru: That's not required to solve his initial problem, and not the best way to solve the next problem he's going to face.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
def list_decreaser(list1):  
      listresult = [] 
      for i in list1:
          list1 = list[:-1]  
          listresult.append(list1) 
      return listresult
```